# How to modify this JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.autocomplete to display search suggestions. 
Right now the function takes the value and insert it behind "/collections/".

I like to give each tag a custom url.
If anyone could show me how to do implement this would be awesome.

```js
$(function(){
  var tags = [      
    { value: 'product1' },
    { value: 'product2' },
    { value: 'product3' },
    { value: 'product4' }
  ];
  
  $('#autocomplete1').autocomplete({
    lookup: tags,
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
    return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
    },
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    document.location.href = "/collections/" + $(this).val()
    }
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.24/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<form method="get" id="searchbar" action="/search"> 
  <button type="submit" value="Search">
    <span class="icon-search"></span>  
  </button>  
    <input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" id="autocomplete1" placeholder="Search"/> 
</form>
```

So something like this:

```
$(function(){
  var tags = [      
    { value: 'product1', url: '/collections/product1' },
    { value: 'product2', url: '/collections/product2b' },
    { value: 'product3', url: '/collections/product3a' },
    { value: 'product4', url: '/collections/product4b' }, 
  ];
```

Comment: can you please show the html to go alongside this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `ui.item.{parameter}`, so in your case, `ui.item.url`

in this instance when you click on a value from the autocomplete the `ui.item` is set to:

```
[object Object] {
  label: "product1",
  url: "/collections/product1",
  value: "product1"
}
```

which you can then easily select the url and point the document location

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    { 
      url: '/collections/product1',
      value: 'product1' 
    },
    { 
      url: '/collections/product2b',
      value: 'product2'
    },
    { 
      url: '/collections/product3a',
      value: 'product3'
    },
    { 
      url: '/collections/product4b',
      value: 'product4'
    }
    ];
  
    $( "#autocomplete1" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function (event, ui) {                 
        document.location.href = ui.item.url;      
      }

    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" id="autocomplete1" placeholder="Search"/> 
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a solution that works with pure jquery.autocomplete?

Comment: change the select function to: onSelect: function (suggestion) {
       document.location.href = suggestion.url;   }  change the source to lookup